# ESP32: Getting Guru Meditation Error because having an extremly long string (~15.000 characters long)

Tags: c++, string, runtime-error, stack-overflow, esp32

I've written a little program, which in a loop first sends a POST-request to a special machine, the machine returns an other API-path in its response header, afterwards I can execute a GET-request on that API path and get an extremly long string (~ about 15.000 characters). This works pretty fine - the string is returned and I can print it afterwards. But then something really strange happens: After each print of the string, my ESP seems to restart somewhy. Please see Output:

```
005    03.07.     08:25
========================
ENDE NC NL

Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
Core 1 register dump:
PC      : 0x4015c44c  PS      : 0x00060430  A0      : 0x800d30f2  A1      : 0x3ffb1dc0  
A2      : 0x3ffb1f10  A3      : 0x00000000  A4      : 0x00003de8  A5      : 0x00003de8  
A6      : 0x3ffd9098  A7      : 0x00003de8  A8      : 0x800d5105  A9      : 0x3ffb1da0  
A10     : 0x3ffd7938  A11     : 0x3f4015a2  A12     : 0x00000002  A13     : 0x0000ff00  
A14     : 0x00ff0000  A15     : 0xff000000  SAR     : 0x0000000a  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000010  LBEG    : 0x400014fd  LEND    : 0x4000150d  LCOUNT  : 0xffffffff  

Backtrace: 0x4015c44c:0x3ffb1dc0 0x400d30ef:0x3ffb1de0 0x400d3161:0x3ffb1e00 0x400d1ae2:0x3ffb1e20 0x400d6301:0x3ffb1fb0 0x40088b9d:0x3ffb1fd0

Rebooting...
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1044
load:0x40078000,len:8896
load:0x40080400,len:5816
entry 0x400806ac
Connecting
```

`ENDE NC NL` is the last line of the string, one line is maximal 24 characters long and ends with `\n` (LF), the program starts with `Connecting`.

If I do not print the string directly, but first do some string "manipulation" operations and than try to print the manipulation result, the first 2 or 3 rounds the `Guru Meditation Error` is shown, then suddenly the ouput changes to the following:

```
Connecting
..
Connected to WiFi network with IP Address: 192.168.200.244
Timer set to 5 seconds (timerDelay variable), it will take 5 seconds before publishing the first reading.
POST-Request to: https://192.168.200.101/api/vdai-daten
HTTP Response code: 201
Header Payload: /api/vdai-daten/vdai-daten.txt
=> GET-Request to: https://192.168.200.101/api/vdai-daten/vdai-daten.txt
2nd HTTP Response code: 200
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Unhandled debug exception)
Debug exception reason: Stack canary watchpoint triggered (loopTask) 
Core 1 register dump:
PC      : 0x400d55b4  PS      : 0x00060236  A0      : 0x800d57e9  A1      : 0x3ffaf5c0  
A2      : 0x3ffb005c  A3      : 0x00000025  A4      : 0x00000000  A5      : 0x0000ff00  
A6      : 0x00ff0000  A7      : 0xff000000  A8      : 0x80000000  A9      : 0x3ffaf5a0  
A10     : 0x3ffb0050  A11     : 0x3f4016d2  A12     : 0x00000001  A13     : 0x3ffb1cc0  
A14     : 0x00000000  A15     : 0x3ffb0060  SAR     : 0x0000000a  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000001  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x4000c46c  LEND    : 0x4000c477  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000  

Backtrace: 0x400d55b4:0x3ffaf5c0 0x400d57e6:0x3ffaf5e0 0x400d1afd:0x3ffaf600 0x400d63e9:0x3ffb1fb0 0x40088b9d:0x3ffb1fd0

Rebooting...
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1044
load:0x40078000,len:8896
load:0x40080400,len:5816
entry 0x400806ac
Connecting
..
Connected to WiFi network with IP Address: 192.168.200.244
Timer set to 5 seconds (timerDelay variable), it will take 5 seconds before publishing the first reading.
POST-Request to: https://192.168.200.101/api/vdai-daten
HTTP Response code: 201
Header Payload: /api/vdai-daten/vdai-daten.txt
=> GET-Request to: https://192.168.200.101/api/vdai-daten/vdai-daten.txt
2nd HTTP Response code: 200
***ERROR*** A stack overflow in task loopTask has been detected.
abort() was called at PC 0x4008c69c on core 1

Backtrace: 0x4008c454:0x3ffaf430 0x4008c685:0x3ffaf450 0x4008c69c:0x3ffaf470 0x40089768:0x3ffaf490 0x4008b3cc:0x3ffaf4b0 0x4008b382:0x833dcfb1

Rebooting...
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1044
load:0x40078000,len:8896
load:0x40080400,len:5816
entry 0x400806ac
Connecting
```

Anyone had something like this before or can explain what is happening/wrong and how I can handle / deal with this 15.000 characters long string?^^

Would be really happy for every answer,

Best regards

P.S.: Please finally let me add my code... the commented part is the string "manipulation" part.

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

const char* ssid = "MyWiFiName";
const char* password = "MyWiFiPassword";

const char* serverName = "https://192.168.200.101/api/vdai-daten";

unsigned long lastTime = 0;

unsigned long timerDelay = 5000;

const char * headerKeys[] = {"HeaderKey"} ;
const size_t numberOfHeaders = 1;

String payload;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("Connecting");
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to WiFi network with IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  Serial.println("Timer set to 5 seconds (timerDelay variable), it will take 5 seconds before publishing the first reading.");
}

void loop() {
  if ((millis() - lastTime) > timerDelay) {
    //Check WiFi connection status
    if(WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED){
      HTTPClient http;

      Serial.print("POST-Request to: ");
      Serial.println(serverName);

      http.begin(serverName);

      http.collectHeaders(headerKeys, numberOfHeaders);      
      http.setAuthorization("Username", "Password");

      http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     
      // Send HTTP POST request
      int httpResponseCode = http.POST("kassierung=false");
      
      Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
      Serial.println(httpResponseCode);

      String headerServer = http.header("HeaderKey");
      Serial.print("Header Payload: ");
      Serial.println(headerServer); 
    
      // Free resources
      http.end();

      HTTPClient http2;
      String newServerName = "https://192.168.200.101" + headerServer;
      Serial.print("=> GET-Request to: ");
      Serial.println(newServerName);
      http2.begin(newServerName.c_str());
      http2.setAuthorization("Username", "Password");
      httpResponseCode = http2.GET();
      Serial.print("2nd HTTP Response code: ");
      Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
      Serial.println("=> Big string: ");
      payload = http2.getString();
      Serial.println(payload);

      /*
      //Count amount of lines
      int counter = 0;
      for (int i=0; i < payload.length(); i++){ 
        if(payload.charAt(i) == '\n'){ 
          counter++;
        }
      }
  
      //Divide big string into a array, where each entry is one line
      String sa[counter]; 
      int r=0; 
      int t=0;
      for (int i=0; i < payload.length(); i++){ 
        if(payload.charAt(i) == '\n') { 
          sa[t] = payload.substring(r, i); 
          r=(i+1); 
          t++; 
        }
      }

      Serial.println("=> First line: ");
      Serial.println(sa[0]);
      */
  
      http2.end();      
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("WiFi Disconnected");
    }
    lastTime = millis();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's clearly a stack overflow issue!

Either use malloc'ed memory for storing string instead OR increase task stack size for `loopTask` to about 20K.

Comment: For a stack overflow, you would need to have a deep call stack or dynamic allocation on the stack. I can't see any of these.